# tapOnCalloutAccessoryControl delegate method not getting called on acessory view tap in mapbox mapview

Tags: ipad, ios7, mapbox, mbtiles

I am working on my app using [mapbox sdk](http://mapbox-ios-sdk.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)(MapBox iOS SDK 1.0.3) and installed the framework using steps as described  [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/#binary).

Now when i add the annotation on the map then i am able to show the title,subtitle,left/right accessory views but the accessory view's tap functionality is not working.

I have tried [these](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/examples/callout-accessory-view/) [solutions](http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/mapbox-ios-sdk/1222-annotation-button-calls-second-mapviewcontroller) as described in these discussions but still **i am not able to get tap functionality to work on my left and right accessory view** and its driving me nuts to why this is happening as this is just a basic functionality.I have read a lot of discussions in mapbox support and tried most of the solutions but to no use.

Please help me on where i am getting wrong.i have looked into this project too- "weekend-pics".but i am not understanding why **these two methods** -

`- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation`

and

`- (void)tapOnCalloutAccessoryControl:(UIControl *)control forAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation onMap:(RMMapView *)map`

are not being called directly on the contrary the should be called as these are delegate methods and should be triggered when accesory view of callout is tapped.

I have tried using `[self mapView:mapView layerForAnnotation:annotations];` then i get the compiler to go into this mehtod-

`- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation`

but still the - `- (void)tapOnCalloutAccessoryControl:(UIControl *)control forAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation onMap:(RMMapView *)map`  method doesnot gets called when i try to click on the right accesory view of the annotation.

I have  added #import "MapBox/MapBox.h" in my file. do i need to add any other file too for this functionality to work? and i have debugged using Breakpoints but the control never goes inside these two methods as described above.

1. I am using Mbtile file and using it as an offline map in my app.
2. Xcode5,ios7
   Please guys help me solve this issue.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are setting your `mapView.delegate`? These are delegate callback methods. You can do this either in code or in the XIB, if you add your map view that way.

Comment: it was a blunder i did in my code. thanks for the advice.i had added this already-->     @interface ViewController : UIViewController<RMMapViewDelegate>  but forgot to add this-"mapView.delegate=self;" in my  viewcontroller.m file as stated by you.its working like a charm now.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have one more question in this regard - i am using multiple mbtile files as layer on default mapview ,now my gesture stops working on second layer i add above the default layer.what should i do for that issue.why is this happening.i read somehwere in the discussions that mapbox enables interaction only in one layer ata time but once i add a layer how to enable interaction on new layer and stop interaction on default layer?please guide me on this.Thanks for your instant help !!

Comment: The single layer interaction refers to embedded interaction in the UTFGrid format, typically encoded with TileMill, and it doesn't refer to gestural interaction of normal `UIView` objects. When you say your gesture stops working, does that mean it just doesn't register, or that it does initially and then starts having problems? Could you provide a bit more info about what is happening?